# Flutter WebviewScaffold pops after Screen pops

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a very simple implementation of the flutter `WebviewScaffold` from the `flutter_webview_plugin` package.

When I pop my screen that embeds the Webview Scaffold, the screen pops first and then the Webview  remains on the screen for 1/2 second and then pops. Am I doind something wrong ?

```
class _EYWebviewPageState extends State<EYWebviewPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebviewScaffold(
      appBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        leading: CupertinoButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          child: Image.asset('assets/img/navigation/common/close-icon.png'),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
        ),
      ),
      url: widget.url,
      clearCache: true,
      appCacheEnabled: true,
      withJavascript: true,
      withLocalStorage: true,
      hidden: true,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to incorporate a `WillPopScope` in order to close the plugin when the screen is popped. Also, using `maybePop() instead of pop()`

Here is the full build:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        await FlutterWebviewPlugin().close(); // Close the plugin so that it doesn't overlay anymore
        return true;
      },
      child: WebviewScaffold(
        appBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
          leading: CupertinoButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: Image.asset('assets/img/navigation/common/close-icon.png'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.maybePop(context),
          ),
        ),
        url: widget.url,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`CupertinoNavigationBar` needs CupertinoPageScaffold. But `WebviewScaffold` uses `Scaffold`. That's why you are observing this behavior.

You can use `AppBar`, instead of `CupertinoNavigationBar`.

Comment: The reason why I am not using `AppBar` is because my app is `Cupertino` based and I dont have any `Material`...

Comment: actually I added some localization delegate to my CupertinoApp in order to use the `AppBar`. Still I have the same popping issue